# How do I check if form has error in Python? (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

https://imgur.com/rYusFAw

Here is my action, 
create an account but empty the first name field, The red box prompt for the empty field.

```
<label for="first_name" ng-class="{'form-error':regForm.first_name.$error.required &amp;&amp; showRegError}"> First Name </label>
<input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="reg.first_name" required="" ng-class="{'form-error':regForm.first_name.$error.required &amp;&amp; showRegError}" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

After red box prompt shows.

```
<label for="first_name" ng-class="{'form-error':regForm.first_name.$error.required &amp;&amp; showRegError}" class="form-error"> First Name </label>
<input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="reg.first_name" required="" ng-class="{'form-error':regForm.first_name.$error.required &amp;&amp; showRegError}" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required form-error">
```

How do I check if the red box prompt is present?
and sorry English is not my native language, the sentence may be incorrect.

Comment: FYI, imgur is currently undergoing maintenance so images are not showing up correctly, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357690/imgur-returning-503-service-unavailable?cb=1)

Comment: I just found how to get CSS value, since I using the wrong attribute, is "value_of_css_property"  not "getCssValue".

Comment: I will pay more attention next time, thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using something along these lines:

```
prop = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).value_of_css_property('border-top-color')
return prop == u'rgb(202, 202, 198)'
```

Basically, I am checking for the actual colour value of the border property. The property name and the colour value might vary in your case.

Comment: hey
thanks for your help, I also found the attribute ".value_of_css_property"